# 1000 rows limit for chef-api module/wrapper

Tags: node.js, chef-infra

So im using this Node module to connect to chef from my API.

https://github.com/normanjoyner/chef-api

The same contains a method called "partialSearch" which will fetch determined data for all nodes that match a given criteria. The problem I have, on of our environments have 1386 nodes attached to it, but it seems the module only returns 1000 as a maximum.

There does not seem to be any method to "offset" the results. This module works pretty well and its a shame this feature is not implemented since its lack really breaks the utility of such.

#### Does someone bumped into a similar issue with this module and can advise how to workaround it?

Here its an extract of my code :

```
chef.config(SetOptions(environment));
        console.log("About to search for any servers ...");
        chef.partialSearch('node',
        {
        q: "name:*"

    },
         {
          name: ['name'] ,
         'ipaddress': ['ipaddress'] ,
         'chef_environment': ['chef_environment'] ,
         'ip6address': ['ip6address'],
         'run_list': ['run_list'],
         'chef_client': ['chef_client'],
         'ohai_time': ['ohai_time']

         }
        , function(err, chefRes) {
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum is 1000 results per page, you can still request pages in order. The Chef API doesn't have a formal cursor system for pagination so it's just separate requests with a different `start` value, which can sometimes lead to minor desync (as in an item at the end of one page might shift in ordering and also show up at the start of the next page) so just make sure you handle that. That said, the fancy API in the client library you linked doesn't seem to expose that option, so you'll have to add it or otherwise workaround the problem. Check out https://github.com/sethvargo/chef-api/blob/master/lib/chef-api/resources/partial_search.rb#L34 for a Ruby implementation that does handle it.

Comment: Yeah. Thats exactly the functionality im trying to add to the module. So, I have done the modifications, and my call looks like this : https://mychefserver/search/node?q=*:*&start=0&rows=1000. But Chef replies to me with  :  401 - Invalid signature for user or client 'ro-client-prod'

Comment: If I remove the "?q=*:*&start=0&rows=1000" then Chef replies with the results, but If I add it then I get the 401

Comment: BTW , I also tried : ?start=0&rows=1000 and ?rows=1000

Answer (score 0):

We have run into similar issues with Chef libraries.  One work-around you might find useful is if you have some node attribute that you can use to segment all of your nodes into smaller groups that are less than 1000.

If you have no such natural segmentation friendly already, a simple implementation would be to create a new attribute called segment and during your chef runs set the attribute's value randomly to a number between 1 and 5.

Now you can perform 5 queries (each query will only search for a single segment) and you should find all your nodes and if the randomness is working each group will be sized about 275 (1386/5).

As your node population grows you'll need to keep increasing the number of segments to ensure the segment sizes are less than 1000.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply Tom Weiss. Im about to attempt a modification on this chef-api module. I I get it to work, Ill send it to you, If dont, ill use your approach. Lets see what happens.

Comment: We largely built our own chef api on top of knife, python, and the sh module.  It's what we've found effective.  If I recall correctly, the same 1000 row limit exists in the PyChef (at least one certain versions).  I can't recall if the user can change it.

Comment: Yep. Exactly what im trying to do. I can see here : https://docs-archive.chef.io/release/11-12/chef_search.html  that a query like this should work : https://youchefserver/search/node?q=*:*&sort=&start=0&rows=20, and the library  is doing exactly that call, except for the "?q=*:*&sort=&start=0&rows=20". So, according the documentation on Chef themselves, If I modify the library so it will paginate the results, I should be able to solve this once and for all. But when im trying im getting a '401 - Invalid signature for user or client ro-client-prod'

Comment: Hi buddy! thanks for your help on this. Just in case you are interested in knowing, I have forked and modified the module so it will return up to 2000 rows which is what I need right now. Later on ill modify it so it will support a limitless amount of nodes.  https://github.com/elMatidelUru/chef-api

Comment: Good to hear.  Keep in mind that as your count of nodes continues to grow, a segmentation scheme may become important; regardless of its use in search.